# How can I have a python script safely exit itself?

Tags: python, windows, exit

Heres the scenario I have a password that must be entered if entered wrong the script will not proceed and just exit itself? But how can I tell the script to safely exit itself?

I tried `sys.exit()` but that gives a traceback error and doesn't seem like a very clean exit method.

Comment: Was the error `NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined`? Calling `sys.exit()` exits cleanly for me.

Comment: The traceback error only exists in IDLE, that is the correct way to exit a program.

Comment: Alright thank you that was what I was trying to get at cause I wasn't sure if it was poor coding to do a sys.exit() and if it causes issues.

Comment: @harry next time, you should show the traceback error along with your question.. helps diagnose the problem sooner. Cheers.

Comment: @Josh Will do sorry about im still getting use to this awesome website!

Comment: Oh right, one more thing. The reason that exists in IDLE is because IDLE catches and traces all exceptions, and sys.exit() throws an exception. This won't be that big of a deal for you unless you try to put it into a `try: except: pass` (which is bad practice anyways) where it will fail to exit the program.

Comment: You can throw away the `sys` part and just use `exit()` which is the same function (this is apparently undocumented, or at least I can't find documentation for this, but it's been like this since at least python 2.5).

Comment: @l4mpi No, it is slightly different. `sys.exit` is a `<built-in function exit>`, but `exit` is a `<class 'site.Quitter'>` object.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `sys.exit()` will only throw a `SystemExit` exception, which would make the program exit if this exception wasn't catched, but I don't think it's poor coding.

Anyway, another possibility is to use `os._exit(0)` if you need to exit immediately at any cost. (cf. http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit)

Answer (score 1):

you are using the `sys` module, but you haven't imported it.

add this before the `sys.exit()` line :

```py
import sys
```